# Erro ao compilar projeto

Tags: c#, .net

Estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem realizar o `build` no projeto.

**Erro**

> A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
>
> Files : Model1.cs Model1.Context.cs Line 1 Column 1

Você também pode visualizar o erro clicando [aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64yvT.png).

Outra coisa, tenho dois HD na minha máquina. O Visual Studio está instalado em uma partição em uma partição diferente do sistema operacional.

Quando adiciono ao projeto um Entity datamodel ele busca na partição `C:` a referencia para DLL do Entity. Só no arquivo `Model.tt` e ao compilar o projeto dá erro pois ele não encontra a DLL no caminho da partição `C:`.

**Alguém sabe como mudar essa referencia ?**

Comment: Pode postar o código que o erro está apontando?

Comment: Então eu ainda nem comecei a escrever os códigos em si.
Eu apenas criei um projeto classlibrary e adcionei um entity datamodel

Comment: @TarcisioVitor coloque o seu codigo dentro de uma classe `public class AMinhaClasse { \\ o meu codigo aqui }` .

Comment: @Omni, desculpe... fico trocando entre os SO e me confundi completamente. 
TarcisioVitor, Os erros estão apontando para dois arquivos, Model1.cs e Mode.Context.cs. Você poderia colocar o conteúdo desses arquivos na sua pergunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, a própria mensagem de erro já diz.

Você não pode inserir variáveis ou métodos fora de uma classe, fere o princípio da orientação a objeto.

Provavelmente sua classe está muito grande e você não percebeu que está tentando inserir artefatos fora dela. Apenas verifique se onde está inserindo, está dentro das chaves da classe. 
( Dentro de Namespaces, você pode inserir apenas classes )